# Date Format need to be

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, encoding

I'm having an issue loading a CSV file into Pandas and then into a database.
The issue appears to be the encoding of the file though the error output is referring to the date-format.

`ValueError: time data '2018-01-10 00:00:00.000' does not match format '%d.%m.%y'`

When opening the CSV file in a text editor the date field values are shown in the following way:
`10-01-18` instead of `10-01-2018`.

I've opened the CSV file in a text-editor, saved with encoding `utf-8` but the error persists. 
Also when I open the CSV file in Excel the date values are correctly displayed when select the cell as `10-01-2018`. Prior to selecting the cell the value appears as `10-01-18`.

The code snippets below reads in the file to a dataframe and later I have a function that is set to convert the date values to a syntax that is useable in the database  - `%d-%m-%Y`. 
The function usually receives an array of date fields, for simplicity I give it one field.

Code snippet:

```
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='utf-8', sep=';', keep_default_na=True, header=0)

def filter_date_values(df, date_cols=['report_date']):

    for col in date_cols:
        if col in df.columns:
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                z = df.ix[index, col]
                if isinstance(z, unicode):
                    py_date = datetime.strptime(str(z), '%d.%m.%Y')
                    if py_date > pd.Timestamp.max:
                        df.ix[index, col] = pd.Timestamp.max
                    else:
                        x = py_date
                        df.ix[index, col] = x.date()
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Or I should change here.

Thanks.

Comment: The date format string doesn't match with date string. `datetime.strptime('2018-01-10 00:00:00.000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` should convert the date to a datetime object. I have assumed that hours in your datetime string are in the 24-hour format. See this [table in the docs for more information about available format directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You have three issues:

1. You have data of the form `2018-01-10 00:00:00.000` and yet with `py_date = datetime.strptime(str(z), '%d.%m.%Y')`, you're telling Python that year appears at the end of the string. If all your data has the year at the beginning of the string, then you need to tell Python to look for it there.
2. You have not only the date but the time, but you're not telling Python how to parse that part.
3. You're telling Python that your deliminator is `.`, when in fact it is `-`.

The simplest thing to do is simply use a default parser, such as `pd.to_datetime`. If you want to use an explicit format, you should move %Y to the front, change the `.` to `-`, and either strip out the time portion (e.g. `z = z.split(' ')[0]`) or say how you want that parsed. You should also look at whether you want the date interpreted as being day first, then month (%d-%m), or month first, then day (%m-%d).

As a broader issue, you seem to have simply copied code from somewhere at dropped it into your program without understanding what it does and why.

A final note: you can use `apply` to cast functions over columns. So you can just do

```
for col in date_cols:
    if col in df.columns:
        df[col] = min(df[col].apply(pd.to_datetime),pd.Timestamp.max)
```

Comment: thanks for the information. Its a code i've used on a similar use-case but it appears the data is much different than anticipated. I looked into it and see why this is happening. Thanks for the advice and heads.